# Macro to prompt for worksheet and copy chosen worksheet to open workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get the macro to run thus: opening a window and asking a file to choose; then type the name of the tab in a window; copy the contents of the tab; and finally paste the contents into the existing tab in the workbook I have open. (The one that contains the button for the macro.)

```
Public Sub frm_File_Name_Click()

Dim cFileLocation As Variant
Dim cFileName As Variant
Dim cFileSource As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim iRow As Long
Dim cSheetTab As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Msg, Style, Title, Help, Ctxt, Response, MyString

Dim Check, Counter
Check = True: Counter = 0 ' Initialize variables.


On Error Resume Next

'Msg = "Is there more tabs in this workbook that need to bt entered ?"    ' Define message.
Style = vbYesNo + vbCritical + vbDefaultButton2    ' Define buttons.
Title = "MsgBox Demonstration"    ' Define title.
Help = "DEMO.HLP"    ' Define Help file.
Ctxt = 1000    ' Define topic

Set ws = Worksheets("worksheet")

'Open Windows folder and select workbook
 NewFN = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls) or (*.xlsx), *.xls", Title:="Please select log file")
    If NewFN = False Then ' On Cancel
        MsgBox "Stopping because you did not select a file"
        Exit Sub

    Else

        Workbooks.Open Filename:=NewFN 'Open selected workbook Request form
     End If
 cFileSource = ActiveWorkbook.Name 'store open workbook Request form as cFilterSource
  Workbooks.Open cFileSource
'Do
    Workbooks(cFileSource).Activate
    'cSheetTab = InputBox("Sheet Tab?", "Tab Name") 'Get workbook sheet name
 'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 Dim x As Integer
    Sheets(cSheetTab).Activate
    i = 0
        Do
            i = i + 1
            If (Err.Number = 9) Then
                On Error Resume Next
                cSheetTab = InputBox("Please enter a Tab label. If after 3 entries of a non-existant tab label, this macro will end. Please enter a correct tab label now", "Tab label Entry Try #" & i)
                Sheets(cSheetTab).Activate

            End If
               If i = 3 Then
               Check = False
               NewFN = MsgBox("You have not entered a correct tab for 3 times, this macro will end", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "This macro is ending")
               Workbooks(cFileSource).Close SaveChanges:=False
               Exit Sub
             End If
        Loop Until (Err.Number <> 9 Or Check = False) 'check to see if you have a good sheet name or if a wrong tab name has been entered more than three times,(error out of range 9)

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False


        fileStr = Application.GetOpenFilename()
Worksheets("Sheet1").TextBox1.Value = fileStr


Dim wbk1 As Workbook, wbk2 As Workbook

Set wbk1 = ActiveWorkbook
Set wbk2 = Workbooks.Add(fileStr)

wbk2.Sheets(1).Cells.Copy wbk1.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1)

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to explain what specifically isn't working right for you.

Comment: specifically, the copy and past functions don't work. I can pick me he file and open the tab, but nothing copies from the tab I pick to the open worksheet. 
The name of the source (copy) data changes, but the name of the destination tab (paste) will stay the same. This is why I need to be able to pick a workbook and worksheet name.

Comment: I thought you'd have been helped by now, but seeing this is still unanswered I found some time to take a look at it. I see a copy command though strangely written, and no Paste/PasteSpecial command. You would usually use copy on the object you are copying, and paste on the object you're copying to, so: _wbk2.Sheets(1).Cells.Copy_ as one command and _wbk1.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial' as the other (with maybe some parameters as needed).